# Courses on "Secure Software Development"

Tags: academia, professional-education

This semester, I'm offering a course on "secure software development". The course is divided into three parts:

- Secure Software Engineering
- Reverse Engineering
- Secure Coding

Do you know of any courses (especially, those offered at universities) with similar content, that you advise me to look at? I don't want my students to feel that only Windows suffers from security issues; so both generic courses and courses specific to 'NIX-based OS's are appreciated.

Comment: Funny to flag as off-topic a Q that attracted 14 answers.  Obviously the wider community does not consider this out of bounds.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For Reverse Engineering: The University of Helsinki in collaboration with F-Secure offer a course titled [Malware Analysis and Antivirus Technologies](https://noppa.tkk.fi/noppa/kurssi/t-110.6220/etusivu) which has the curriculum available online.
For Secure Coding: [CERT](http://www.cert.org/secure-coding/) is always a good reference, especially for C & C++. They have a [Secure Coding in C and C++](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/training/p63.cfm) course at SEI @ CMU.

Comment: Funny that someone from Las Vegas suggests a course a university here in Finland. Are we that good here ;)

Comment: @Peter Smit: I've found out about the course a few years ago via F-Secure's blog. It's a very small world...

Answer (score 8):

I haven't taken the course, but I've heard a lot of good things about the OCSP certification:

http://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-certifications/

Answer (score 7):

A few years ago, I helped set up (via the local branch there of my then-company) a similar course at the University of Amsterdam... but I really don't have any current details, though you should be able to look that up.

The IDC in Israel has a very good program for infosec - http://portal.idc.ac.il/en/schools/cs/progs/ugrad/Pages/securityintheNetEra.aspx. They produce a lot of good research, and are very connected with OWASP.

Answer (score 7):

I find this awesome - http://pentest.cryptocity.net/. This is course done by many well-known security researchers. There is no point in discussing, just check out.

Comment: that's the old site (down). it's now at http://cryptocity.squarespace.com

Comment: @seedy, I see no difference. Researchers usually publish their updates link in twitter pointing to site that I have mentioned. And for me it is up and running.

Comment: @Ams, it seems we're both half right. cryptocity.squarespace.com works everywhere, but pentest.cryptocity.net only works outside of the ip subnet of the school that the class is taught at.

Comment: @Ams your link doesnt work here either, but the squarespace one did :)

Answer (score 6):

SANS offer some courses relating to your areas that I have heard good things about. I suggest them because they have a good break down of the topics they cover that might give you some good ideas.

[Secure Coding in Java/JEE: Developing Defensible Applications](http://www.sans.org/security-training/secure-coding-java-jee-developing-defensible-applications-912-mid)

[Reverse-Engineering Malware: Malware Analysis Tools and Techniques](http://www.sans.org/security-training/reverse-engineering-malware-malware-analysis-tools-techniques-54-mid)

Comment: "How to Get Started With Malware Analysis" by Lenny Zeltser (Instructor for Reverse-Engineering Malware course at SANS Institute) http://blogs.sans.org/computer-forensics/2010/11/12/get-started-with-malware-analysis/

Answer (score 5):

The University of Pisa offered a course on "Secure Software Development" a year ago.

You can download all the lectures and resources from the [official page](http://www.cli.di.unipi.it/doku/doku.php/magistralesicurezza/sss/risorse) (it's in Italian, so maybe you'll need Google Translate).

Answer (score 4):

Have you taken a look at [MIT's OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/)? After a quick search I found a course on [Network and Computer Security](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-857-network-and-computer-security-fall-2003/) and [Computer Systems Architecture](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-823-computer-system-architecture-fall-2005) (might be useful for the Reverse Engineering part).

You can also try http://academicearth.org/lectures/search/security/ and http://videolectures.net/site/search/?q=security.

Answer (score 3):

This course I took at UCSD is similar and very useful

https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp10/cse127/

Answer (score 3):

Stanford University offers an online set of short courses in software security, leading to a [Certificate in Advanced Computer Security](http://scpd.stanford.edu/public/category/courseCategoryCertificateProfile.do?method=load&certificateId=1145836#searchResults). The program includes an introductory course on secure software development, and short courses in secure protocols and cryptography, web security, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The Aspect Security courses appear to have the best content. I don't think too many university programs can match what they have done, but the http://pentest.cryptocity.net one mentioned by Ams in these comments is definitely better than most.

Answer (score 2):

**Special Course in Communications Security (Malware Analysis and Antivirus Technologies)**

The course teaches students what malicious code is and how it can be detected and analyzed. Topics of the course include malware taxonomy, reverse engineering, code emulation fundamentals, basic cryptoanalysis of malicious crypto, and antivirus engine basics. Course includes a homework project that requires programming skills.

http://www.tml.tkk.fi/Opinnot/T-110.6220/2008/

Answer (score 2):

**Full disclosure:** I work for Varonis.

Troy Hunt put together a (free) video course for Varonis on web security which covers things like SQL injection, XSS, Transport Layer Security and more.

Even though the content was sponsored by Varonis, it's completely vendor agnostic.

You can view all 7 video lessons here: http://info.varonis.com/web-security-fundamentals-course

It's a great way to get the fundamentals down before moving onto something more in-depth.

Hunt also has a bunch of PluralSight courses on ethical hacking, Azure security, and more. He's an excellent teacher.

Answer (score 1):

Langara College offers, or at least they did offer, a security course:

CPSC 2810 (3 credits) (4:0:2)
Computer and Information Security

An introduction to the policies, mechanisms, and implementations of computer security. Provides an understanding of threats, including script kiddies; covert channels; and malicious logic such as viruses, worms, time bombs, and trap doors. Students will learn how attacks work, how to defend against attacks, and how to design and administer secure systems and networks.

Prerequisite(s): A minimum "C" grade in one of: CPSC 1280 or 1480; or permission of the department.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to define a syllabus for "Secure Programming" course. In my search, I found the course outline provided by Cyber Defense Institute so complete and useful. See the following link http://www.cyberdefenseinstitute.net/courses/secureprogramming/secureprogramming.html#attachment. Just finding some good textbooks for preparing the content of such a course makes it a good complete reference for secure coding part of your course and other similar courses.