# How to subscribe to information about new vulnerabilities in selected products?

Tags: zero-day, cve

In order to be informed about critical vulnerabilities in selected products I'd want to subscribe to some list about them. I'd want to configure the list of products by myself.

The question: [Where can I get security breach alerts?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/19980/485) gives information on general lists, however these provide vulnerability information across all products the list knows about, and all I want to see are advisories about the products/applications/services in my network.

Can I subscribe to CVEs for specific products?

Comment: You might want to check http://security.stackexchange.com/q/486/13909 or http://security.stackexchange.com/q/19980/13909 or https://cassandra.cerias.purdue.edu/CVE_changes/

Comment: you can also check https://secureit.io - I built it, ATM it's free, comments are welcome

Comment: It's a shame this is Closed - There are Answers here that I have not been able to find elsewhere on the web.

Comment: @JoãoAntunes when is the last time your application worked?

Comment: how is this question closed? off topic? really? LoL

Comment: secalerts.co is also a free service that's been running for nearly 3 years now that does exactly this. Disclaimer: I run it.

Comment: [opencve.io](https://www.opencve.io/welcome) (ex Saucs) let you subscribe to Vendors and Products and is free.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to CVE Details' [Product](http://www.cvedetails.com/product/12215/Ruby-lang-Ruby.html) or [Vendor](http://www.cvedetails.com/vendor/7252/Ruby-lang.html) pages. There is "Vulnerability Feeds & Widgets" link there.

It allows you to subscribe to CVEs about selected vendor/product.

Comment: You need search for the vendor and replace the vendor ID within the general URL:
http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-feed.php?vendor_id=0&product_id=0&version_id=0&orderby=3&cvssscoremin=0

E.g. Apache vendor: http://www.cvedetails.com/vendor/45/Apache.html
You RSS URL is 
http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-feed.php?vendor_id=45&product_id=0&version_id=0&orderby=3&cvssscoremin=0

Comment: You can then take the RSS feed created by cvedetails and put it into an [ifttt.com](https://ifttt.com) (or something similar) recipe so that it sends you notifications of your choice (e.g. tweets, emails etc).

Comment: CVE Details seems to be pretty neglected. I see recent CVEs in the database, but the site's registration page [has been broken for months](https://cvedetails.uservoice.com/forums/70479-general/suggestions/20536039-fix-registration-and-login-pages). Doesn't exactly promote confidence in the quality of the service.

Comment: @Michael +1 for the hack

Comment: I just went there to check for CVE-2019-5736 (docker/runc, Feb-11th 2019) but it only has vulnerabilities up until 2018.

Comment: Vulmon Alerts (https://alerts.vulmon.com) is a tool dedicated for only this purpose. You can check it.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to make a custom list of products / vendors / keywords using [Cassandra service](https://cassandra.cerias.purdue.edu/main/index.html) from Purdue University. It is free and allows updates to be emailed.

Answer (score 3):

secunia makes a [commercial product](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_intelligence/) that does exactly what you want.

> "The Secunia VIM lets you create specific vulnerability management reports for different product categories across your entire IT infrastructure by filtering criteria. So you only get vulnerability alerts and intelligence relevant to your specific needs."

Comment: Secunia Research service is currently available from Flexera company:
https://www.flexera.com/products/software-vulnerability-research/secunia-research.html

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to this mailing list "bugtraq@securityfocus.com". A lot of vendors and researchers keep updating about new vulnerabilities.