# Best website to learn computer security basics?

Tags: appsec, penetration-test, professional-education

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources to learn about security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/266/resources-to-learn-about-security)

Can someone advice on which are the good sites out there to learn the basics of computer security from?

Comment: @bretik, there is no point in making duplicate items, I have already mentioned where it repeats. That's why I voted to close this question.