# Learning Network Security

Tags: network, professional-education

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources to learn about security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/266/resources-to-learn-about-security)

I'm a software developer. I'm interested in learning Network Security, what is the recommended books, video courses, etc that I can study to learn security?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing [Backtrack linux](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/) on a partition of your hard drive and just learn by example. They have a massive suite of penetration testing software.
Plus it's just a beautiful OS ;]